# ViewController unresponsive for 2-3 seconds after being pushed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

What could cause a viewController to be unresponsive for 2-3 seconds after being pushed? The tableView doesn't scroll, the searchbar can't be tapped.

There's no heavy code on viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear. No complex layouts. Just a simple tableView (even non populating in makes no difference).

Comment: Did you get any crashes or errors while running the code ?

Comment: Are you sure you have not added any webservice call or  any background  task to Main Queue ?

Comment: What you have  in cell for row ? Please add that code

Comment: In what thread do you push?

Comment: I feel like I was looking for the problem that wasn't really there. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Under the Runtime API Checking section, ensure that the **Main Thread Checker** is enabled to see if you are executing ui methods in a non-UI thread

[image]

[image]